# CListCtrl: single column without column headings?

Tags: list, view, report, scrollbar, clistctrl

If I set View = Report, then you get a single column and a vertical scrollbar (what I want).  However you also get an area at the top reserved for column headings even if you don't have column headings (not what I want).

If I set View = List, then no screen space wasted for column headings (what I want) but there are now multiple columns and a horizontal scrollbar (not what I want).

I think I'd be happy if I could use Report mode but just somehow shrink the space reserved for the column headings to zero.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for **`CListBox`**. [See here](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/listbox.htm) for more.
If you would like to continue with CListCtrl then use ***List*** view or ***Small Icon*** instead of ***Report*** view. For more [see here](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/listcontrol.htm).

Comment: Thanks!  I can't remember now whether I didn't know of CListBox, or perhaps was trying to use CListCtrl as I could see the project possibly migrating to multiple columns in the future.  That said, your suggestion answers the question perfectly.